# Getting max(ora_rowscn) - 10 minutes

Tags: oracle

I need to get the data from the table based on when the table was last modified.
the load takes ~10 minutes so I would like to get max(ora_rowscn) minus 10 minutes.

```
select TO_CHAR(SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ORA_ROWSCN) - 600 ),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM table
```

??

Comment: Do you have a column with this information on your table? If yes and index on this column and you got the result immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to and from a timestamp with [`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions161.htm) and [`TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions195.htm):

```
select max(ora_rowscn),
  timestamp_to_scn(scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn))
    - interval '10' minute) as adj
from <your table>;

  MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)               ADJ
----------------- -----------------
   10320929886378    10320929885515
```

In some circumstances you might not be able to convert the SCN to a timestamp, if it's too old  to look it up; then you'll get something like `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number`. Note the bit about SCN to timestamp association in the `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` documentation.

You could possibly bypass the `max` lookup and just use:

```
select timestamp_to_scn(systimestamp - interval '10' minute) from dual
```

... or using the end time of the load process. But you still might not have that association, depending on the time period and your redo retention.

[A flashback query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003) might be simpler here anyway, again assuming you're doing this inside the redo retention period:

```
select * from <your table>
as of timestamp (systimestamp - interval '10' minute);
```

... or as of any timestamp you want to specify.
Having a timestamp column on the table, set by your load process or automatically with a trigger, would be more reliable as it wouldn't rely on redo retention, but perhaps a little slower during the load itself. If this is a one-off check then a flashback query would be simplest though.

Comment: timestamp_to_scn(scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn))
    + interval '10' minute) as adj doesn't work for me :(

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? Does it give you an error? How long ago was the load done - beyond the redo retention?

Comment: @Angelina - if it is in the redo retention period then a [flashback query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003) would probably be simpler anyway, if you want to see how it looked immediately before the load. If it's set up. But again you might be too late...

Comment: Yea... ORA-08186: invalid timestamp specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN", line 1
08186. 00000 -  "invalid timestamp specified"
*Cause:    as stated above
*Action:   enter a valid timestamp

Comment: @Angelina - right, so the load must have completed a while ago, and the SCN/timestamp data is no longer in redo. You can check what the timestamp value is available on its own. Which means flashback won't be available either.

Comment: @Angelina - sorry, I had a `+` instead of a `-`; I think the ORA-08186 was if the latest change was less than 10 minutes ago, with that incorrect code. You get ORA-08181 if it's outside the redo retention.